# It's safer to store data in clear or to encrypt it and store the decryption key?

Tags: security, encryption, language-agnostic

I'm writing an app that needs to deal with important data. I was wondering if it's safer to store these important data in clear form into a program's variable or to store an encrypted version of the data into a variable and the decryption key into another variable.

The problem here is, in my opinion, that if someone gain access to the data in clear form or to the encrypted data along with the decryption key it basically have access to the data anyway.

So, which one is safest and why?

It's safer to store the decryption key into the OS build-in keyring instead to store it into a variable?

Is there any safer way to do this?

Comment: At some point, in order to deal with the data, it will need to be clear. How will you store it then? Otherwise, if you don't need to work with the clear data, then you probably don't need the key at all.

Comment: @deanosaur Yes, at some point I need to have them in a clear form anyway or they will be useless. Btw I want to make the whole process as safe as possible.

Comment: What you want then, is to make sure you're storing the clear data and keys in memory that can be wiped when your done with it. For example, in java, its preferable to use `char[]` instead of `String` to store sensitive info because `char[]` can be overwritten after use, whereas strings are immutable.

Comment: @deanosaur Thanks for your helpful suggestion, I'll surely need to implement this in the future (the program is written in python).

Comment: Who are you trying to hide the data from? Is it the user's data, and you're trying to keep it safe from others?

Answer (score 1):

Sensitive data held in long-term storage should always be encrypted.  Hold the key separately so it cannot be stolen along with the data.  You could keep it on a USB stick in a safe (with a secure backup copy held offsite) and change it regularly.

Data actually being processed will need to be decrypted and held as plaintext.  Ensure that any such data, and the key, is explicitly overwritten before you release the memory.  You may be limited in what you can do by your operating system.  For example, a secure OS will wipe any memory images swapped to disc, which an ordinary OS will not.

Some languages provide secure storage classes for holding things like keys.  Read the documentation to see what is there already.